# Typing math like in MathStack

Tags: mathjax

First I'll begin by apologizing if this is not the right place to publish this post.

I have been studying math in the academy for a while. For that very reason I have to type a lot of math on the computer - whether it's for homework, essays or just for fun. I tried three basics formats - Microsoft Word (MathType), LyX (LaTeX) and here on Mathstack (which is MathJax if I'm not mistaken).

For many reasons that I'd rather not expand on, typing math essays on LyX and Word has been difficult for me. However, the format here on MathStack has always been my favorite. I know most of the commands, and I manage to type Math in a customized, aesthetic way that satisfies me. What is truly funny, is that the number of posts that I wrote here is way smaller than the number of posts I made on the other platforms, yet I find typing here on MathStack the most satisfying. Sometimes I wish I could type my homework here rather than on Microsoft Word.

My question is rather simple - What is the program / website you recommend that is similar to the Math format here on Mathstack the most? And when I say similar I mean same commands, same way of typing progress: For instance, the preview that we have here along the typing, the fact that you can see the commands all the way rather than they transforming automatically to the math symbols, and generally the many ways of customization the format here on Mathstack provide you with.

I'll apologize again if it's not the right place to ask but this question has stumbled me for quite a few days and I realized that asking here might my best shot at the moment.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I guess that since you are asking here, you are looking for a (La)TeX editor with immediate preview. Maybe the thread [What's the fastest way to preview changes as I learn TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16914/110998) answers your question. E.g., one post advertizes an immediate preview for WinEdt

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because mathjax is off-topic and the post appears to be intended for Math SE.

Comment: Note that MathJax isn't even active on this site i.e. TeX SE. If you type maths commands here, they'll never transform to symbols ever.

Comment: Let me suggest https://liyasthomas.github.io/marcdown/. Use the regular `$$<newline>Math<newline>$$` syntax.  

Note that I am not in any way affiliated with this.